# When is a file available to download from Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backend

I can't find some information about Amazon S3, hope you will help me. When is a file available for user to download, after the POST upload? I mean some small JSON file that doesn't require much processing. Is it available to download immediately after uploading? Or maybe amazon s3 works in some sessions and it always takes a few hours?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel),

> Amazon S3 provides strong read-after-write consistency for PUTs and DELETEs of objects in your Amazon S3 bucket in all AWS Regions.

This means that your objects are available to download **immediately** after it's uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

An object that is uploaded to an Amazon S3 bucket is available right away. There is no time period that you have to wait. That means if you are writing a client app that uses these objects, you can access them as soon as they are uploaded.

In case anyone is wondering how to programmatically interact with objects located in an Amazon S3 bucket through code, here is an example of uploading and reading objects in an Amazon S3 bucket from a client web app....

[Creating an example AWS photo analyzer application using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app)